# I have a 'start date' and 'end date' column. I want to turn each line into X lines, one for each of the inclusive dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, intervals

I'm stuck with a small data transformation problem.
Here's the data I have:

```
    start_date  end_date   ticket   info
    1/1/2020    1/3/2020   A        A_info
    1/5/2020    1/10/2020  B        B_info
```

And I wish to turn it into a format like this:

```
    ticket  date      info 
    A       1/1/2020  A_info
    A       1/2/2020  A_info
    A       1/3/2020  A_info
    B       1/5/2020  B_info
    B       1/6/2020  B_info
    ...
    B       1/10/2020 B_info
```

Where the number of lines per item each correspond to one day in the initial interval provided.  I find it much easier to edit/analyze once loaded in a BI system if it's in this format.  What's the easiest way to do this in pandas?  I've already gotten the date array for each row by doing something like this:

```
dates = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range((end-start).days)]
```

But what' the fastest way to iterate through the rows and extend/duplicate them with the proper dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for expand rows and then convert Series to DataFrame with swap values and index and use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for add all another columns, last remove unnecessary columns:

```
s = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,pd.date_range(r.start_date, r.end_date)) 
               for r in df.itertuples()])
df1 = (pd.DataFrame({'date':s.index}, s)
         .join(df).drop(['start_date','end_date'], axis=1)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
        date ticket    info
0 2020-01-01      A  A_info
1 2020-01-02      A  A_info
2 2020-01-03      A  A_info
3 2020-01-05      B  B_info
4 2020-01-06      B  B_info
5 2020-01-07      B  B_info
6 2020-01-08      B  B_info
7 2020-01-09      B  B_info
8 2020-01-10      B  B_info
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) for upsampling:

```
# combine date columns
df = df.melt(id_vars=['info', 'ticket'], value_name='date').drop('variable', axis=1)
# convert column 'date' to DateTime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
# upsample dataframe and fill missing values
df.set_index('date').resample('d').asfreq().bfill()
```

Output:

```
              info ticket
date                     
2020-01-01  A_info      A
2020-01-02  A_info      A
2020-01-03  A_info      A
2020-01-04  B_info      B
2020-01-05  B_info      B
2020-01-06  B_info      B
2020-01-07  B_info      B
2020-01-08  B_info      B
2020-01-09  B_info      B
2020-01-10  B_info      B
```